# Open vpn not working ubuntu 16.04

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-16.04, vpn-client

I have installed open vpn access server,
Also installed OpenVPN 2.3.10 as client,
I've downloaded client.ovpn file for my account

With open vpn server running, when i do

```
openvpn client.ovn
```

i get below message

```
Wed Mar  8 14:51:06 2017 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Wed Mar  8 14:51:06 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  8 14:51:06 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  8 14:51:06 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->200000] S=[212992->200000]
Wed Mar  8 14:51:06 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Wed Mar  8 14:51:06 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]192.168.0.137:1194
Wed Mar  8 14:51:10 2017 Server poll timeout, restarting
Wed Mar  8 14:51:10 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,server_poll] received, process restarting
Wed Mar  8 14:51:10 2017 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Wed Mar  8 14:51:10 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  8 14:51:10 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  8 14:51:10 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->200000] S=[212992->200000]
Wed Mar  8 14:51:10 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Wed Mar  8 14:51:10 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]192.168.0.137:1194
Wed Mar  8 14:51:14 2017 Server poll timeout, restarting
Wed Mar  8 14:51:14 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,server_poll] received, process restarting
Wed Mar  8 14:51:14 2017 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth using INLINE static key file
Wed Mar  8 14:51:14 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  8 14:51:14 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Mar  8 14:51:14 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->200000] S=[16384->200000]
Wed Mar  8 14:51:14 2017 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]192.168.0.137:443 [nonblock]
Wed Mar  8 14:51:14 2017 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]192.168.0.137:443 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Connection refused
Wed Mar  8 14:51:14 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,init_instance] received, process restarting
Wed Mar  8 14:51:14 2017 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

And that's it, the message keeps reappearing and i won't get a success connection message.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Post the server log from `192.168.0.137`, this is the client log.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek , how do i view server logs ?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a server listening (or responding), check if service is running at all, if firewall blocks it...

Side note: SHA1 is considered broken, you should use a different encryption mechanism